# Add pull to refresh to WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to add pull to refresh to a webview app. I've seen some tutorials and many similar questions but my code is different and I'm not sure where to add the `UIRefreshControl`. When I say 'my code' its not really my code, rather taken from [this repo](https://github.com/khmyznikov/ios-pwa-wrap)

Here's my code:

```
func createWebView(container: UIView, WKSMH: WKScriptMessageHandler, WKND: WKNavigationDelegate, NSO: NSObject, VC: ViewController) -> WKWebView{
    
    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    
    
    let webView = WKWebView(frame: calcWebviewFrame(webviewView: container, toolbarView: nil), configuration: config)
    webView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    webView.isHidden = true;
    webView.navigationDelegate = WKND;
    webView.scrollView.bounces = true;

    return webView
}

extension ViewController: WKUIDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
        if (navigationAction.targetFrame == nil) {
            let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
            refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshWebView(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
            webView.scrollView.addSubview(refreshControl)

            webView.load(navigationAction.request)
        }
        return nil
    }

    @objc func refreshWebView(_ sender: UIRefreshControl) {
        print("triggered reload");
        MyProject.webView?.reload()
        sender.endRefreshing()
    }
}
```

I can pull on the page but the refresh indicator doesn't appear. What am I missing?

(I'm very new to swift and iOS programming)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these lines to viewDidload method

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshWebView(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
        webView.scrollView.addSubview(refreshControl)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I was seeing this function but thought I didn't have it in this repo. I found it in another file ViewController.swift

Comment: yes file ViewController.swift and the extension ViewController both are the same class but maybe the user create two different files for easy to read out long classes. Every class that subclass of UIViewController has a override viewDidLoad function that run once only when present/navigate it